# Error thrown when clicking image button in datalist

Tags: c#, imagebutton, datalist

I have a datalist that displays images that I want to use as buttons, so I used the image button.  But when I click the image, I get an error before it even gets to the if(e.CommandName == "imgButton") line. All I get is: 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown, I'm at a total loss. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dlImages" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" OnItemCommand="dlImages_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgButton" runat="server" CommandName="imgButton"
    CommandArugment='<%# Eval("id")%>' 
    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("url")%>' Style="max-width: 200px" />
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:DataList>



protected void dlImages_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
           {
              if(e.CommandName == "imgButton")
               {
                  string taid = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                  ShowModel(Toolkit.ToInt32(taid, 0));
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was to not bind my datalist on postback. And currently, something is very wrong with this page.  Like I need 3D glasses to read it.